# How to get values of radio button in php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I am trying to modify a joomla component and more specific a questionnaire that contains radio buttons. In php file the code is :

```
 <form id="form-table" action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_bisbas&task=table.save'); ?>" method="post" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="iframe1">
        <ul>
         <input type="hidden" name="jform[id]" value="<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="jform[state]" value="<?php echo $this->item->state; ?>" />
         <?php echo $this->form->getInput('timecreated'); ?>            <div class="control-group"><br><br><br>
         <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('question1'); ?></div>
         <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('question1'); ?></div><br><br>
```

and in firebug code is :

```
     <div class="controls">
     <fieldset id="jform_question1" class="radio" aria-required="true" required="">
     <input id="jform_question10" type="radio" aria-required="true" required=""    value="Yes" name="jform[question1]">
      <label for="jform_question10">Yes</label>
      <input id="jform_question11" type="radio" value="No" name="jform[question1]">
      <label for="jform_question11">No</label>
      <input id="jform_question12" type="radio" value="I am not sure" name="jform[question1]">
      <label for="jform_question12">I am not sure</label>
     </fieldset>
     </div
```

I want when the user clicks the answer of radio button to check the value and print an alert. But I don't know how to do this in php file. I understand that

```
   <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('question1'); ?></div>
```

prints the radio values based in an xml file that contains the values but how can I get them and check the value when the user selects it?

Comment: Giveng an alert when the user clicks something is in the browser and therefore in the domain of Javascript - not PHP. So your question is not clear.

Comment: I used javascript and I managed to alert the values of "Yes","No" etc. Like this:
js(document).ready(function(){
        js('#form-table').submit(function(event){
    
           alert($("jform_question10").value);
    document.form2.submit();
       }); 
     });

But If I try to get the value of the checked radio with jform_question1 it prints nothing. I tried also with fieldset like:
document.getElementById("jform_question1") but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your query I think that You must use javascript.
If your Joomla version is above 3.0, You can do it with jQuery :

`jQuery('#radio_selector').on('click', function(){//verification script});`